# What is the relationship between the stack and the process table?

Tags: kernel, cpu, processes, stack

According to Wikipedia and many other sources,

> Since PCB contains the critical information for the process, it must
>   be kept in an area of memory protected from normal user access. In
>   some operating systems the PCB is placed in the beginning of the
>   *kernel stack* of the process since that is a convenient protected
>   location.

It makes a lot of sense: when a switch occurs, the current context has to be saved somewhere and a (kernel) stack looks a good place to do that. However, Tanenbaum states that

> To implement the process model, the operating system maintains a table
>   (an array of structures), called the **process table**, with one entry
>   per process . (Some authors call these entries **process control blocks**.)

Later, Tanenbaum mention that the process context is saved onto a stack. Clearly, the process table and the stack are different beasts and now I am confused: what is the relationship between the stack and the process table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanenbaum is just saying that there are two common ways of storing information about a process. How a particular OS chooses to do that — on some kernel stack or in a table/array — is just one of the myriad freedoms available to the OS designer.

The OS designer doesn't even have to call them [process control blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block).

Comment: Hum, so the conceptual issue I was trying to spot actually was a language issue. Perhaps that "process table" is an array of handlers, in the same fashion the processes queues (ready, blocked, etc) are implemented? I mean, logically a queue is a set of PCBs pointing to each other as in a linked list, but its physical implementation is likely to resemble an array of handlers to those PCBs. Probably, this "process table" is implemented the same way?

Comment: @HumbertoFioravanteFerro: Point me at a particular bit of code, and I can tell you whether we're talking about an array, or a queue, or a linked list or whatever. Give me prose instead and I can't tell you how a "table" is implemented. It could be any of those things or none of them.